# What is the difference between "certificate" and "certification"?

Tags: word-usage, differences, vocabulary

Could someone please provide examples of the differences between *certificate* and *certification*?

According to the Oxford Dictionary, **certificate** is:

- an official document attesting a certain fact, in particular.
- a document recording a person's birth, marriage, or death.
- a document attesting a level of achievement in a course of study or training.
- a document attesting ownership of a certain item.

**Certification** is an official document attesting to a status or level of achievement.

It also is the action or process of providing someone or something with an official document attesting to a status or level of achievement.

Comment: I've used the free dictionary and merriam-webster it stated that "Certificate" is A document issued to a person completing a course of study; and certification is the process to complete the certificate but i found some people says : india launches quality assurance certification. people often use the two words interchangably it confuses me

Comment: The use of certification is utterly correct in that sentence.... they've launched a method to achieve a certificate in "quality assurance"... I think it's your interpretation that's the problem, not the usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A certificate is the actual object.

> I have a certificate of completion.

This means you have something, typically a piece of paper or an electronically verifiable thing.

A certification is typically the process of getting a certificate (or the completion thereof).

> I have a certification in computer repair.

This means that you have completed a certification process.  It may imply that you also have a specific certificate, but it's not explicitly certain.

> Full Definition of [certificate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/certificate)
>
> 1:  a document containing a certified statement especially as to the truth of something; specifically :  a document certifying that one has fulfilled the requirements of and may practice in a field
>
> 2:  something serving the same end as a certificate
>
> 3:  a document evidencing ownership or debt

Also:

> Full Definition of [certification](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/certification)
>
> 1:  the act of certifying :  the state of being certified
>
> 2:  a certified statement

Comment: Thanks mate, but could you explicate the example you've provided " I have a certification in computer repair. " do you mean that certificate is a synonym of  certification ?

Comment: Not precisely, no.  It does seem a matter of semantics, but they are not strictly synonymous.  One can hold a certification in something without having a physical certificate, though having a physical certificate implies that one is certified in something.  Think of it this way - if I gain a certification in computer repair, but it expires in two years, three years from now I may still have a certificate (physical items, though expired), but I no longer technically have a certification (current state of being certified).  Does that help?

Comment: So, I guess that the implication of a physical certificate meaning someone is certified is also not strictly true.  It's implied, but not guaranteed.